# Image inside Highcharts ring

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have created a highcharts ring using donut visualization. The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/1141/).
I have an image in .png file. How do i embed that image inside this ring ?

```
.png
```

The code that would essentially need to be changed is here :

Comment: Looks like you forgot the code.

Comment: Not sure where the code for image insertion will be put. Rest of the code is in jsfiddle in the link http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/1141/

Answer (score 3):

I edited an existing jsfiddle to add an image, as you need.

URL: http://jsfiddle.net/e2qpa/1349/

The related code with your question:

```
chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 220, 200, 60, 60)
   .add();
});
```

Documentation of HighChart:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image